# PHP Detect if public property is being set or changes

Tags: php, getter-setter, public

Is there a way to detect if public property is being set or changes?

The `__set` method won't react to setting public properties (only private, protected or non-defined properties).

I don't want to use a method to set the property (like `setMyPropery()`) and using private or protected properties is not an option in my case.

Comment: No, the only way I see to do this is using the magic `__set` method with private or virtual properties.

Comment: I think you can use `__get();` and `__call();` is well https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Comment: I'm curious as to what is the use case here

Comment: I think its not possible to obtain your expected output using a public property